# Adding rows that have the same column value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with dates and hours as columns. Now I want to add the hours of the same dates. For example to make this:

```
7-1-2016 | 4
7-1-2016 | 2
4-1-2016 | 5
```

Into this:

```
7-1-2016 | 6
4-1-2016 | 5
```

Is there a quick way to do this on big files?

Comment: Can you post raw data, code to reproduce your df, you code lacks column names. Anyway I think this would work: `df.groupby('date')['hours'].sum()`

Comment: I now see that I forgot to include some code, but this seems to be working. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here `GroupBy` can be used to provide the desired output.

```py
DataFrame.groupby(by=None, axis=0, level=None, as_index=True, sort=True, group_keys=True, squeeze=False)
```

Group series using mapper (dict or key function, apply given function to group, return result as series) or by a series of columns.

Try:

```py
df.groupby('date')['hours'].sum()
```

Comment: This seemed to be working, but it is not adding up to the right values everywhere. I think this has to do with the fact that the hours are DateTime objects. This is an output I get for example:    2013-12-30   0 days 08:00:00

Comment: Nevermind, there was an error in my data. It works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the index to the date allows you to use the resample method (as well as lots of other time series functionality). If you have other analysis to do, I suggest:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['datecol'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['Hourcol'].astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d %H')
df = df.resample('1d', how='sum') # defaults to mean
```

If the columns are already strings, then omit the .astpye(str)'s as necessary. However,

```
df.groupby('datecol').sum()['Hourcol']
```

will also work if this is the only analysis you want to do. You may need to add a .astype(int) if the hour column is not numeric.